# refit: keep original exception from api

Tags: c#, api, refit

I used a middleware to handle exceptions from the api, like this: `app.UseMiddleware<ApiErrorHandlerMiddleware>()`
In the middleware, I customed the api response like this:

[image]

Use refit, I want to keep the original exception from api, instead of the exception like this:

```
Refit.ApiException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
   at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2.<<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/Refit/RequestBuilderImplementation.cs:line 288
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In order to deviate from Refits standard behavior regarding non success HTTP status codes you will need to modify your return type of the interface of the Refit client.

The documentation has a chapter dedicated to it called [Handling exceptions](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#handling-exceptions)

The gist of it is:

> Refit has different exception handling behavior depending on if your
> Refit interface methods return `Task<T>` or if they return
> `Task<IApiResponse>`, `Task<IApiResponse<T>>`, or `Task<ApiResponse<T>>`.

So in order to change the exception handling behavior of Refit you will need to change the return type of the method. In your case most likely to `Task<IApiResponse<T>>`. Where T is your response type. You can then do something like:

```
var response = await _myRefitClient.GetSomeStuff();
if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   // Happy stuff
}
else
{
   _logger.LogError(response.Error, response.Error.Content);
   // Do your error things
}
```